# .load doesn't work without alert before

Tags: javascript, jquery, load

i have this code but doesn't work

index.html

```
<html>
<body>
 <section>

 </section>
</body>
</html>
```

welcome.html

```
<div>Welcome, please login</div>
<div id='login'> </div>
```

file.js

```
$('section').load('welcome.html');                          
$('#login').load('login.html');
```

but if i put an alert like this, and then close the alert it works

```
$('section').load('welcome.html');

alert("!!");                        
$('#login').load('login.html');
```

what can i do? i don't want that alert, thank you for the your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you're seeing is due to the fact that [jQuery.load()](https://api.jquery.com/load/) works asynchronously.

Therefore, when you place the `alert()` in between the two calls, you give a chance to the first call to complete, and then the second call works. Without that `alert()`, the first `load()` hasn't completed yet when the second `load()` is called.

Use a callback function to fix:

```
$('section').load('welcome.html', function() {
    $('#login').load('login.html');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

As $.load() function is asynchronous you need to wait for the callback to do the next load();

```
$('section').load('welcome.html', funcion() {
    $('#login').load('login.html');
});
```